# how to call function inner function from outer one assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
   var x = function outer() { 
      console.log('outer')
      this.inner = function() {
          console.log("inner");
      }
  }
```

The question is how can I call the inner function outside this scope? I tried `x().inner()` but it doesn't work

Comment: when using `this` you need to use `new`, so like `new x().inner()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't return this from the outer function, can I access inner function from x variable? - [*Tarik Ziyad's* (OP) comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267590/how-to-call-function-inner-function-from-outer-one-assigned-to-a-variable#comment104743464_59267675)

If you want to execute **only** the inner function, you might be for something like this then (or a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)):

```js
var outer = function () {
  this.inner = function() {
    return 'inner';
  }
  return 'outer';
}
outer.prototype.innerProto = function() {
  return 'inner-proto';
}
var x = new outer;
console.log(x.inner());
console.log(x.innerProto());
```

Comment: That is Perfect! I'm a little bit confused about the using of new, what it is meaning here? do we create an object from a variable structure? Thanks

Comment: @TarikZiyad yes! `new` is just a way to create an instance of the newly defined structure. In [MDN's prototype page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) they say: "Since JavaScript doesn't exactly have sub-class objects, prototype is a useful workaround to make a “base class” object". And then they instantiate several _Employees_ and _Customers_ who are "inner" classes of _Person_ (which has a "inner" `greet` function with a log) through the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to use a type function as a Class 
try this:

```
  class Outer {

     inner () {
         console.log("inner");
     }
   }
   console.log(new Outer.inner()) //output inner
```

here some ref https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your `outer` function does not return a value.

What happens in your code is that, when you run `x()`, it will execute `outer` function, which is going to `log` something to console, declare `this.inner` and exit.

What you need to do is to return `this` at the end of `outer` function.

Like this:

```
var x = function outer() { 
    console.log('outer')
    this.inner = function() {
        console.log("inner");
    }

    return this;
}
```

Then you can do `x().inner()` and it will work perfectly!

Comment: yes, it is working perfectly! but in my original code I can't return this from the outer function, can I access inner function from x variable?

Comment: No, you can not. That's the point of scopes. What is declared in the inner scope can not be accessed from the outer scope. Without returning the `inner` function, you can not access to it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

in the way you do it.

this keyword is pointing to window Object so if you want to call inner you can just

use window.inner();

but if you want to use it as a method you must use new keyword.
new keyword create a new object and assine the this keyword to it so inner can be a method for something in my example.

```js
function Outer() { 
    console.log('outer')
    this.inner = function() {
        console.log("inner");
    }
}

var something = new Outer();
    something.inner();
```